# Add 'view finder' to a stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a stacked bar chart, pretty much a clone of the demo site [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html).

What I want is a view finder like the [line with focus](http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html) chart has.  Only problem is, these seem to be a bit too 'out of the box'.

How do I get the view finder feature on a different chart?

Answer (score 1):

When NVD3 can't do the visualisation you're looking for, chances are you'll need to learn D3 and do it yourself.

I recommend studying [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) for your use-case. The general technique is (with links to lines of the example in parentheses)—

1. bind the same data to two differently-scaled charts ([here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1667367#file-index-html-L89-L92) and [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1667367#file-index-html-L103-L106)), then
2. create a [brush object](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush) ([here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1667367#file-index-html-L49-L51)) and render it into the context chart ([here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1667367#file-index-html-L113-L118)), then
3. set up the [brush's event handlers](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush_on) to scale the focus chart based on its [extent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush_extent) ([here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1667367#file-index-html-L121-L125)).